# python - group values when generating a json

Tags: python, django

I am generating below JSON using a piece of code.
Basically, I need to group my generated JSON group by continent, and then country and languages

```
[
    {
        "continent": "South America",
        "regions": [
            {
                "region": "ar",
                "country": "Argentina",
                "languages": [
                    {
                        "language": "en-us"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "region": "ar",
                "country": "Argentina",
                "languages": [
                    {
                        "language": "es-ar"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "region": "bo",
                "country": "Bolivia",
                "languages": [
                    {
                        "language": "es"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "region": "bra",
                "country": "Brazil",
                "languages": [
                    {
                        "language": "en-us"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "region": "bra",
                "country": "Brazil",
                "languages": [
                    {
                        "language": "pt-br"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }}
```

I am generating above JSON using the below code.

```
 def get_available_locales_json():
    locales = []
    for locale in get_available_locales():
        append_locale = True
        for entry in locales:
            if entry['continent'] == locale.region.continent:
                entry['regions'].append({'region': locale.region.code,
                                         'country': locale.region.name,
                                         'languages': [
                                             {'language': locale.language.code}
                                         ]})

                append_locale = False
                break

        if append_locale:
            locales.append(
                {
                    'continent': locale.region.continent,
                    'regions': [{'region': locale.region.code,
                                 'country': locale.region.name,
                                 'languages': [
                                     {'language': locale.language.code}
                                 ]}]
                }
            )

    return locales
```

However, I need to group languages together without having an extra node for the country.
something like below,

```
[
    {
        "continent": "South America",
        "regions": [
            {
                "region": "ar",
                "country": "Argentina",
                "languages": [
                    {
                        "language": "en-us",
                        "language": "es-ar"
                    }
                ]
            }
            }]
```

I tried many ways to get this done, but I cannot come up with solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work providing the locales are all sorted, otherwise you will have to sort them

```
from itertools import groupby
locales = []
available_locales = sorted(get_available_locales(), key=lambda l: (l.region.continent, l.region.code))
for continent, continent_locales in groupby(available_locales, lambda l: l.region.continent):
    regions = []
    for (region, name), region_locales in groupby(continent_locales, lambda l: (l.region.code, l.region.name)):
        regions.append({
            "region": region,
            "country": name,
            "languages": [{'language': l.language.code} for l in region_locales]
        })
    locales.append({
        "continent": continent,
        "regions": regions
     })
```

Comment: Thank mate, data are all sorted. I am getting below error,
```
   for continent, continent_locales in groupby(get_available_locales(), lambda l: l region.continent):
                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Ah sorry it's `l.region.continent` not `l region.continent`

Comment: The issue was in the languages comprehension, should be `l.language.code` not `locale.language.code`

Comment: :) .Spot on. Thanks Mate.

Comment: I just realized my data set is not sorted. any easy way to do this mate?

Comment: Added a line that should sort your data

Comment: must use keyword argument for key function

Comment: Just need to add `key=` to the sorted call

Comment: The only issue now is languages not grouping together, they are working the same as my original code. creating separate entries :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203941/discussion-between-iain-shelvington-and-s-s-niranga).